# Why is typedef can not be used in local in systemveriliog?

Tags: system-verilog

Why is typedef can not be used in local in systemveriliog?

I am referencing from http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/data_types7.html

I have problem  when I use struct instead of typedef struct. Why does it not use?

Comment: what exact problem/error you are facing if you use only struct instead of typedef?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question "why typedef cannot be used locally?"
Typedef can be used inside any SystemVerilog module and can be accessed/initialized based on our needs. Refer Section 6.18 User-defined types of SV LRM [IEEE 1800 - 2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)

Here is one example which uses typedef inside the module

```
struct { //using struct without typedef 
  byte a;
  reg  b;
  shortint unsigned c;
} myStruct;

module struct_data ();

struct {
  byte a;
  reg b;
  shortint unsigned c;
} myLocalStruct = '{11,1,101};

typedef struct {  //using typedef inside the module
real r0, r1;
int i0, i1;
logic [ 7:0] opcode;
logic [23:0] address;
} instruction_word_t;

instruction_word_t IW;
assign IW = '{ real:1.0,default:0};

assign myStruct = '{10,0,100};

initial begin
  #1;
  $display ("a = %b b = %b c = %h", myStruct.a, myStruct.b, myStruct.c);
  $display ("a = %b b = %b c = %h", myLocalStruct.a, myLocalStruct.b, myLocalStruct.c);
  $display ("r0 = %b r1 = %d opcode = %h ,address = %h ",IW.r0, IW.r1, IW.opcode,IW.address);
  #1 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

For your second question, we can also use struct without using typedef and I have shown in the example above.

output of the above code

```
a = 00001010 b = 0 c = 0064
a = 00001011 b = 1 c = 0065
r0 = 00000000000000000000000000000001 r1 =           1 opcode = 00 ,address = 000000
```